# Добавление товара в корзину

Tags: php, get

Всем привет! 
Сейчас у меня добавляется товар в корзину в количестве по умолчанию 1.
Вот код:

```
   <div>
...картинка товара
...описание и т.д.

        <a href="<?=PATH?>addtocart/<?=$product['goods_id']?>"><img src="путь к картинке" alt="Добавить в корзину" /></a>
    </div>
```

Затем $_GET-ом передаю значение товара.

```
$goods_id = abs((int)$_GET['goods_id']);
addtocart($goods_id);

/* ===Добавление в корзину=== */
function addtocart($goods_id, $qty = 1){
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id])){
        // если в массиве cart уже есть добавляемый товар
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] += $qty;
        return $_SESSION['cart'];
    }else{
        // если товар кладется в корзину впервые
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] = $qty;
        return $_SESSION['cart'];
    }
}
/* ===Добавление в корзину=== */
```

Сейчас у меня $qty задано 1, а как сделать так чтобы количество товара передавалось из поля допустим input в переменную (как передается сейчас $_GET-ом id товара) и подставить вместо $qty=1 просто $qty.

То есть мне надо передать значение количества товара (которое выбрал посетитель) по клику на кнопку "добавить в корзину".

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас описана работа с GET и `SESSION`. Для передачи количества Вам нужна еще одна переменная. Если она будет браться из input, тогда Вы должны работать с POST. Это простейший пример работы.

```
<form action="/">
<input type="text" name="count" value="?"/>
<input type="hidden" name="goods_id" value="id"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

В дальнейшем лучше заменить это на ajax

```
$goods_id = abs((int)$_POST['goods_id']);
$count = $_POST['count'];
addtocart($goods_id, $count);

/* ===Добавление в корзину=== */
function addtocart($goods_id, $qty = 1){
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id])){
        // если в массиве cart уже есть добавляемый товар
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] += $qty;
        return $_SESSION['cart'];
    }else{
        // если товар кладется в корзину впервые
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] = $qty;
        return $_SESSION['cart'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! То есть теперь мне придется убрать ссылку  `<a href="<?=PATH?>addtocart/<?=$product['goods_id']?>"><img src="путь к картинке" alt="Добавить в корзину" /></a>` и заменить её на кнопку submit? А больше ни как? Хотелось бы оставить мою ссылку. Может можно передать значение с помощью js? Так как у меня передается id товара в в шаблон addtocart

Comment: ну как по мне тут GET передавать не удобно. Но если очень нада, можно js менять ссылку и отправлять что-то вроде

<a href="<?=PATH?>addtocart/<?=$product['goods_id']?>&count=1"><img src="путь к картинке" alt="Добавить в корзину" /></a>

просто подставить не выйдет. так как количество может изменится
Тут удобно использовать POST+ajax

Comment: а не могли бы Вы показать, как это сделать на ajax. Очень нужно. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: вот очень доступно
http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC_POST

Comment: Что-то не получается, вот что настряпал:
`<form method="post" action="<?=PATH?>addtocart/<?=$product['goods_id']?>">
<input id="kol" type="text" name="count" value="2" />
<input id="id" type="hidden" name="goods_id" value="<?=$product['goods_id']?>" />
<input id="sub" type="submit" alt="Добавить в корзину" />
</form>`

Comment: `$("#sub").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var kol = $("#kol").val();
        var id = $("#id").val();
        var sub = $("#sub").val();
        $.ajax({
           url: '<?=PATH?>addtocart/<?=$product['goods_id']?>',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {sub: sub, kol: kol, id: id},
           success: success,
           error: function(){
                alert("Error!");
           }
        });
    });`
Не особо понимаю ajax

Comment: Поможете мне написать?